# Config class not found when unit testing laravel package

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, package

I'm working on a Laravel (5.4) package, and I'm trying to do unit testing. I have this class :

```
<?php

namespace Sample;

class Foo
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = \Config::get('test');

        return $config;
    }   
}
```

I have this test :

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Sample\Foo;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetConfig()
    {
        $foo = new Foo;
        $config = $foo->getConfig();
    }
}
```

When I execute phpunit I have this error :

> Error: Class 'Config' not found

How can I unit test this class ?

Thank you.

Comment: include vendor autoload

Answer (score 5):

Instead of extends `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`, you should extends `Tests\TestCase`:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Unit;

// use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Sample\Foo;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetConfig()
    {
        $foo = new Foo;
        $config = $foo->getConfig();
    }
}
```

Moreover, `Config` or other Laravel facades may not work in `@dataProvider` method, please see [Laravel framework classes not available in PHPUnit data provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710631/laravel-framework-classes-not-available-in-phpunit-data-provider/33301265#33301265) for more info.

Comment: The Tests\TestCase class uses the CreatesApplication trait. PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase does not. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to mock the dependencies in your code. In this case you are depending on an outside class (Config). Usually I test it like this:

```
// make sure the mock config facade receives the request and returns something
Config::shouldReceive('get')->with('test')->once()->andReturn('bla');

// check if the value is returned by your getConfig().
$this->assertEquals('bla', $config);
```

Obviously, you need to import the Config facade in your test.

BUT: I would inject the Config class in the constructor in my real code, instead of using the facade. But that's me... :-)

Something like this

```
class Foo
{
    /** container for injection */
    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = $this->config->get('test');

        return $config;
    }   
}
```

And then test it by injecting a mock Config into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and yes the answers are working, now here is the problem, what if I am **developing a package** and using **pest** to test it?

I solved the problem by adding this entry

```
uses(
    Tests\TestCase::class,
)->in('Unit', 'Feature', '../packages/vendor/package-name/tests/Unit');
```

to the

> tests/Pest.php

hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try by including like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```

Comment: Different error :
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.